# how to set animations using images

Tags: objective-c

Hi
     I have some five images to show a star blinking (dull to bright).how should i use this image to show the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Put all images into an array and assign that array to UIImageView's `animationImages` property:

```
NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, nil];

UIImageView *star = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[star setAnimationImages:imagesArray];
```

Then add that UIImageView to some UIView (controller view or anything else) and start animating:

```
[someView addSubview:star];
[star startAnimating]
```